# Solutions of two linear programming

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, maxima-minima

Let $\beta\equiv (\beta_0, \beta_1)\in \mathcal{B}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathcal{B}$ compact. $\beta$ is a known vector of parameters.

Let $P_0, P_1, F_0, F_1$ be know parameters, each in $[0,1]$.

Consider the following linear programming problems.

\begin{aligned}
 \underline{p}(\beta)\equiv \min_{a,b}  & [P_0-a]F_0+ [b - P_1]F_1 \\
&\text{ s.t. } \\
& 1) \text{ }a\in [0,1]\text{,  }b\in [0,1]\\
& 2) \text{ }Q_0: \{0, \beta_0, \beta_0+\beta_1\} \rightarrow [0,1] \text{ with } Q_0(0)=\frac{1}{2}\text{, } Q_0(\beta_0) = P_0 \text{, } Q_0( \beta_0+\beta_1)= a\\
& \text{ is weakly increasing}\\
& 3) \text{ } Q_1: \{0, \beta_0, \beta_0+\beta_1\} \rightarrow [0,1] \text{ with } Q_1(0)=\frac{1}{2}\text{, } Q_1(\beta_0) = b \text{, } Q_1( \beta_0+\beta_1)= P_1\\
&\text{ is weakly increasing} 
 \end{aligned}

and

\begin{aligned}
\bar{p}(\beta)\equiv \max_{a,b}   & [P_0-a]F_0+ [b - P_1]F_1 \\
&\text{ s.t. }\\
& 1) \text{ }  a\in [0,1]\text{,  }b\in [0,1]\\
& 2) \text{ } Q_0: \{0, \beta_0, \beta_0+\beta_1\} \rightarrow [0,1] \text{ with } Q_0(0)=\frac{1}{2}\text{, } Q_0(\beta_0) = P_0 \text{, } Q_0( \beta_0+\beta_1)= a\\
& \text{ is weakly increasing}\\
& 3) \text{ } Q_1: \{0, \beta_0, \beta_0+\beta_1\} \rightarrow [0,1] \text{ with } Q_1(0)=\frac{1}{2}\text{, } Q_1(\beta_0) = b \text{, } Q_1( \beta_0+\beta_1)= P_1\\
&\text{ is weakly increasing} 
 \end{aligned}

---

**Question:** Is it true that $\forall p \in [\underline{p}(\beta),\bar{p}(\beta)]$, there exists $\tilde{\beta}\in \mathcal{B}$ such that

\begin{aligned}
& 1) \text{ } [P_0-a]F_0+ [b - P_1]F_1 = p \text{ has a solution wrto $a,b$}\\
& 2) \text{ }  a\in [0,1]\text{,  }b\in [0,1]\\
& 3) \text{ } Q_0: \{0, \tilde{\beta}_0, \tilde{\beta}_0+\tilde{\beta}_1\} \rightarrow [0,1] \text{ with } Q_0(0)=\frac{1}{2}\text{, } Q_0(\tilde{\beta}_0) = P_0 \text{, } Q_0( \tilde{\beta}_0+\tilde{\beta}_1)= a\\
&  \text{ is weakly increasing}\\
& 4) \text{ }  Q_1: \{0, \tilde{\beta}_0, \tilde{\beta}_0+\tilde{\beta}_1\} \rightarrow [0,1] \text{ with } Q_1(0)=\frac{1}{2}\text{, } Q_1(\tilde{\beta}_0) = b \text{, } Q_1( \tilde{\beta}_0+\tilde{\beta}_1)= P_1\\
&\text{ is weakly increasing} 
 \end{aligned}
? Why yes or not? I think the answer should be yes, but your hint would be very appreciated.